# Exercise 1.2.4 (From Grimmett and Stirzaker)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is yet another problem, where I have run into trouble.

> Let ${F}$ be a ${\sigma}$-field of the subsets of $\Omega$ and suppose that $B\in{F}$. Show that $G=\{A\cap{B}:A\in{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-field of the subsets of $B$.

I know a $\sigma$-field is, and that it is closed under complementation, countable unions (and hence intersection) and contains the empty set $\phi$. However, I cannot deduce that $G$ is a $\sigma$-field of the subsets of $B$.

Comment: Did you try using the definitions? Can you state what you have to prove in order to show that G is closed under complementation?

Comment: @Isomorphism, let me try.

Comment: Use `\mathscr{F}` to type the $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: @Isomorphism, am still practicing, wasn't intuitive at first. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\varnothing \in \mathcal{G}$ because $\varnothing =\varnothing \cap B$ and $\varnothing \in\mathcal{F}$.
2. Suppose $A_i\in\mathcal{F}, \:i\in\Bbb{N}$. Then 
   $$
   \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(A_i\cap B)=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)\cap B\in\mathcal{G}
   $$
   for $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathcal{F}$ since $\mathcal{F}$ is $\sigma$-field.
3. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is $\sigma$-field, $A\in \mathcal{F}$ means $A^c\in \mathcal{F}$. Thus $A^c\cap B\in \mathcal{G}$.

So $\mathcal{G}$ is $\sigma$-field of the subsets of $B$.

Comment: Thanks @hermes, I understand the solution now.